# PoshRSJob Looping through file directory

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I am trying to loop through a directory (sorting by smallest file), get the path, and the file name and then pump those results into a utility.exe program.

I am trying to do this multi threading with PoshRSJob, but I am not even seeing the utility program show up in task manager, I am getting an error "A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.", for every file that exists (if 50 files are in the directory, then I get 50 errors). I also cannot test if the throttling is working, because nothing is actually running.

```
Import-Module C:\PoshRSJob.psm1
Function MultiThread($SourcePath,$DestinationPath,$CommandArg, $MaxThreads){
    if($CommandArg -eq "import") {
        $fileExt = "txt"
    }else{
        $fileExt = "ini"
    }
    $ScriptBlock = {
        Param($outfile, $cmdType, $fileExtension)
        [pscustomobject] @{
            #get the full path
            $filepath = $_.fullname     
            #get file name (minus extension)
            $filename = $_.basename
            #build output directory
            $destinationFile = "$($outfile)\$($filename).$($fileExtension)"
            #command to run
            $null = .\utility.exe $cmdType -source `"$filepath`" -target `"$destinationFile`"
        }
    }
    #get the object of the passed source directory, and pipe it into start-rsjob
    Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | Sort-Object length | Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $DestinationPath, $CommandArg, $fileExt -Throttle $MaxThreads

    Wait-RSJob -ShowProgress | Receive-RSJob
    Get-RSJob | Receive-RSJob
}
MultiThread "D:\input" "D:\output" "import" 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scriptblock is creating an object where you are defining `$null = .\utility.exe +++` as a property. As it says, value of `$null` (nothing) can't be a property name.. I would suggest just running the lines..

You might also want to change the `Wait-RSJob`-part. You don't specify a job, so it never waits for anything. Try:

Try changing the scriptblock to:

```
Import-Module C:\PoshRSJob.psm1
Function MultiThread($SourcePath,$DestinationPath,$CommandArg, $MaxThreads){
    if($CommandArg -eq "import") {
        $fileExt = "txt"
    }else{
        $fileExt = "ini"
    }

    $ScriptBlock = {
        Param($outfile, $cmdType, $fileExtension)
        #get the full path
        $filepath = $_.fullname     
        #get file name (minus extension)
        $filename = $_.basename
        #build output directory
        $destinationFile = "$($outfile)\$($filename).$($fileExtension)"
        #command to run
        $null = .\utility.exe $cmdType -source `"$filepath`" -target `"$destinationFile`"
    }

    #get the object of the passed source directory, and pipe it into start-rsjob
    Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | Sort-Object length | Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $DestinationPath, $CommandArg, $fileExt -Throttle $MaxThreads

    Get-RSJob | Wait-RSJob -ShowProgress | Receive-RSJob
}
MultiThread "D:\input" "D:\output" "import" 3
```